# Nodejs id lookups to get names from a users tbl

Tags: sql, node.js

I have a table for treatments that has a patient_id and clinician_id - but instead of return the raw data as it is - I want to do a lookup on the user table to get the names of these two users.

I've got a lookup function like this - although want to avoid chaining callbacks.

```
function getUserDetailsById(id) {
  let res = db.query(`SELECT * FROM application.users WHERE id = ${id}`)
  return res
}
```

usage

```
  treatment.patient_name = getUserDetailsById(2).name;
  treatment.clinician_name = getUserDetailsById(3).name;
```

should I just use callbacks like this.

```
function getUserDetailsById(id, callback) { 
  db.query(`SELECT * FROM application.users WHERE id = ?`, [id],  (error, result) => {
    callback(result[0])
  })
}


    getUserDetailsById(treatment.patient_id, function(res){
      treatment.patient_name = res.name;
    });

    getUserDetailsById(treatment.clinician_id, function(res){
      treatment.clinician_name = res.name;
    });
```

Comment: I'd suggest to look into promises. Your SQL library most certainly supports them. If not, use one that does

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2-promise  -- is the callback approach acceptable - it seems stable